# Google Storage Image Serving Cache

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Using the GoogleStorageTools class's `CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl` and then replacing the storage object of the image with another image of the same name, the old image is still displayed upon subsequent calls of `getImageServingUrl`

I tried using `CloudStorageTools::deleteImageServingUrl` and then `CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl` again, but this doesn't work.

Is there any way to interact with Cloud Storage and tell it to refresh the image or the image URL? I'm guessing not, and am going to ensure the filenames are unique, instead, but it feels like there ought to be a way.

Comment: 3 years on and this bug is still present. WTF Google?

Answer (score 1):

If you refresh the image, does the new image show up? It's possible there's a cache-control policy set on the image. Google Cloud Storage allows users to specify what cache-control headers should be sent to browsers, but I'm not sure whether app engine's getImageServingUrl respects that value.

As an experiment, could you try going to console.developers.google.com, heading over to "storage > cloud storage > storage browser", choosing the appropriate object, choosing "edit metadata," and then seeing whether there's a Cache-Control policy on the object? Try changing the cache-control section to "max-age=0,no-cache".